# How to apply update query with IN operator using stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures

Question:

```
update tablename 
set columnname = "12" 
where columnname2 in ('1','2','3','4');
```

It will run with simple query.

How to run above query using a stored procedure  i.e

```
update tablename 
set columname = @param1 
where columnname2 in (@param2);
```

where @param2 have '1','2' etc..

Answer (score 0):

You should create a function which is used to delimit your comma seperated String..

```
  CREATE FUNCTION SplitString
  (    
        @Input NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Character CHAR(1)
  )
  RETURNS @Output TABLE (
        Item NVARCHAR(1000)
  )
  AS
  BEGIN
        DECLARE @StartIndex INT, @EndIndex INT

        SET @StartIndex = 1
        IF SUBSTRING(@Input, LEN(@Input) - 1, LEN(@Input)) <> @Character
        BEGIN
              SET @Input = @Input + @Character
        END

        WHILE CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input) > 0
        BEGIN
              SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input)

              INSERT INTO @Output(Item)
              SELECT SUBSTRING(@Input, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1)

              SET @Input = SUBSTRING(@Input, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@Input))
        END

        RETURN
  END
  GO
```

Now your update Query should be

```
  Update tablename set columname=@param1 
  Where columnname2 in (SELECT Item FROM dbo.SplitString(@param2, ','))
```